# How to create a command toggle?

Tags: command-line

I have a launcher currently on my XFCE panel that I would like to open a window. However, I want to make it only open the window if no other instance is running. If an instance is running, the windows would close upon a press of the launcher. I think that this could be possible with a toggle of the command--if running, close, and if closed, run. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and use `wmctrl` to do something like what you want.

Say you want to start `<program>` only if another instance of it isn't running. If another instance of `<program>` *is running,* switch to it instead.

Run

```
wmctrl -a <something> || <program>
```

or

```
wmctrl -ax <something> || <program>
```

depending on which works for you. `<something>` will be derived from the output of `wmctrl -l` or `wmctrl -lx` which you will run when the program you wish to control is open.

You can then assign a shortcut key to that or use it in a script and make a desktop launcher for that script.